# Converting Tcl to C++

Tags: tcl

I am trying to convert some tcl script into a C++ program.  I don't have much experience with tcl and am hoping someone could explain what some of the following things are actually doing in the tcl script:

```
    1) set rtn [true_test_sfm $run_dir]
    2) cd [glob $run_dir]
    3) set pwd [pwd]
```

Is the first one just checking if true_test_sfm directory exists in run_dir?

Also, I am programming on a windows machine.  Would the system function be the equivalent to exec statements in tcl?  And if so how would I print the result of the system function call to stdout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tcl, square brackets indicate "evaluate the code between the square brackets".  The result of that evaluation is substituted for the entire square-bracketed expression.  So, the first line invokes the function `true_test_sfm` with a single argument `$run_dir`; the result of that function call is then assigned to the variable `rtn`.  Unfortunately, `true_test_sfm` is not a built-in Tcl function, which means it's user-defined, which means there's no way we can tell you what the effect of that function call will be based on the information you've provided here.

`glob` is a built-in Tcl function which takes a file pattern as an argument and then lists files that match that pattern.  For example, if a directory contains files "foo", "bar" and "baz", `glob b*` would return a list of two files, "bar" and "baz".  Therefore the second line is looking for any files that match the pattern given by `$run_dir`, then using the `cd` command (another Tcl built-in) to change to the directory found by `glob`.  Probably `$run_dir` is not actually a file pattern, but an explicit file name (ie, no globbing characters like * or ? in the string), otherwise this code may break unexpectedly.  On Windows, some combination of `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` in C++ could be used as a substitute for `glob` in Tcl, and `SetCurrentDirectory` could substitute for `cd`.

`pwd` is another built-in Tcl function which returns the process current working directory as an absolute path.  So the last line is querying the current working directory and saving the result in a variable named `pwd`.  Here you could use `GetCurrentDirectory` as a substitute for `pwd`.

Comment: That sequence with `glob` is the sort of horrible thing people used to use a lot before Tcl had `file normalize`. That style of using `glob` and `cd` breaks catastrophically when file-/dir-names have spaces in; the list quoting will pretty much guarantee that what happens is not what anyone wants. In Tcl 8.5 upwards, `cd {*}[glob ...]` will at least be less crazy when it fails. (Using globbing to get a directory name for this sort of thing isn't recommended in a script, and it's very lazy in interactive use.)